# Android MenuItem is null

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I am trying to get the menuitem to change the text in it but it is retured as a null

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_beef);
    Log.d("MenuItem", item1.toString());
    item1.setTitle("Omlets");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Most likely the item you're looking for isn't in the menu you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this line:
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

And now run it.

Or better try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

MenuItem item1 = view.findItem(R.id.nav_beef);
Log.d("MenuItem", item1.toString());
item1.setTitle("Omlets");
return true;
```

}